# path is not a valid addons directory

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, add-on, odoo-15

### Hello

following the steps in "ODOO 15 DEVELOPMENT ESSENTIALS FIFTH EDITION" I'm trying to add a custom addons folder using a terminal on Ubuntu (wsl), when I run this command:

```
$ odoo -d 15-library --addons-path="./library,./odoo/addons"
```

I get this error:

> Usage: odoo [options]
>
> odoo: error: option --addons-path: the path './library' is not a valid
> addons directory

btw folder library exists in my path

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: We are going through the same book.  Did you find a solution?  I opened an issue in github repo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is solved by running scaffold command in the directory before running the command in the question .

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer to remove the accept flag?

Answer (score 3):

`./library` folder should contain at least one module, a directory with `__init__.py` file, and a [manifest](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a7f7233e0eae8ee101d745a9813cba930fd03dcb/odoo/modules/module.py#L20)
file (`__manifest__.py` or `_openerp__.py`) at top level as indicated in the [module structure](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/tutorials/getting_started/01_architecture.html#module-structure) section

Odoo will call the [_check_addons_path](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a7f7233e0eae8ee101d745a9813cba930fd03dcb/odoo/tools/config.py#L575) function when you pass `--addons-path` in command line and check if all folders [are valid addons paths](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a7f7233e0eae8ee101d745a9813cba930fd03dcb/odoo/tools/config.py#L557-L566)

```py
def _is_addons_path(self, path):
    from odoo.modules.module import MANIFEST_NAMES
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        modpath = os.path.join(path, f)
        if os.path.isdir(modpath):
            def hasfile(filename):
                return os.path.isfile(os.path.join(modpath, filename))
            if hasfile('__init__.py') and any(hasfile(mname) for mname in MANIFEST_NAMES):
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the library folder contains other non-addons file, I solved it by deleting all other file and just keep the needed addons. For example, my library folder only contains the library_app folder in Chapter3 and it runs perfectly: "library/library_app"