# How can I add the "addons" in pycharm??? I am using Windows

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, odoo, odoo-12

I am working in Windows 10.
I am trying to add the addons in different path ways, but I can't add it. I get this error:

"odoo-bin: error: option --addons-path: the path 'addons' is not a valid addons directory"

I try to add with this sentence:
-r admin -w admin --addons-path addons,/odoo/addons/

I am following a tutorial in Youtube and in that video put that and worked.

I want if someone can please help me with this error

Comment: what does this have to do with pycharm? or even python?

Comment: Odoo raised this error because at least one directory does not contain any module (folder with `__init__` and a manifest file). Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73757665/path-is-not-a-valid-addons-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the space after `--addons-path` with `=`.

So, change from

```
--addons-path addons,/odoo/addons/
```

to

```
--addons-path=addons,/odoo/addons/
```

should make it work.

If the problem still persists, make sure you have the folder `addons` in the right place.